# Update query in php correct layout

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am having a problem with a update query, I believe I have done this right but have not done it before and its not working so I have gone wrong somewhere but do not know where.

any help will be fantastic.

**admin.php**

```
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bands ");

        echo "</br>";


    echo "<table border = '1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Show No</th>
        <th>Band Name</th>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Edit Show</th>
    </tr>";

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<td>" .$row['Band_id']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Venue']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Category']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['Stock']. "</td>";
            echo ("<td><a href=\"editband.php?id=$row[Band_id]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
        }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

**editband.php**

```
      <?php
    require 'core/init.php';
              $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bands where Band_id ='$Band_id'");
              $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
              ?>
              <form method="post" action="ammenddetails.php">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[Band_id]"?>">
                <tr>        
                  <td>Band Name</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" 
                size="20" value="<? echo "$row[Name]"?>">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Venue</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Venue" size="20" 
                  value="<? echo "$row[Venue]"?>">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <input type="submit" 
                  name="submit value" value="Edit">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </form>
?>
```

**ammenddetails.php**

```
     <?php
require 'core/init.php';
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE bands
          SET Name='$Name', 
              Venue='$Venue' 
          WHERE 
          Band_id='$Band_id'");

mysql_query($result);
header("location:admin.php");
?>
```

Comment: What's in $result in ammenddetails.php? And you shouldn't be using **MySql_*** any more, it's depreciated. Check out MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` after the update query.

Comment: I have updated ammenddetails on my question, and yes I have been told about mysqli, but i have not much experience and need to read up on it, i plan to do that one ive completed this project

Comment: @user007 I have tried this but dose not show a error

Comment: I just realized, why do you have `mysql_query()` 2 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ammenddetails.php is missing the POST values
Should be as below-

```
require 'core/init.php';
$Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Name"]);
$Venue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Venue"]);
$Band_id = (int)$_POST["id"];


    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE bands
              SET Name='$Name', 
                  Venue='$Venue' 
              WHERE 
              Band_id='$Band_id'");

    mysql_query($result);
    header("location:admin.php");
```

Comment: omg, been looking at the code for 2 hours. thank you @abhik Chakraborty

Comment: Yes check the data is coming via post, the best is to echo the query and see if all data is there in the query.

Comment: Hmm I have tried this and it just redirects back to admin.php on the event click of the button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45716/discussion-between-abhik-chakraborty-and-beep)

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'core/init.php';
$Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Name"]);
$Venue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Venue"]);
$Band_id = (int)$_POST["id"];


    $query= "UPDATE bands
              SET Name='$Name', 
                  Venue='$Venue' 
              WHERE 
              Band_id='$Band_id'";

    mysql_query($query);
    header("location:admin.php");
```

Try that? You should only need to run the `mysql_query` function once. Build the query string into a variable and run that variable on the `mysql_query` function